# Facebook share the link not displaying image

Tags: facebook

While share our custom image using facebook share link, the image disappear suddenly.  Please find below     link.While debug i found image in that, but it is not displaying.

Appreciate any help on this!

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=Get 1 FREE Fitness Pass To Urban Air Trampoline Park - Limited Number&p[summary]=Click+here+to+get+1+FREE+Fitness+Pass+to+Urban+Air+Trampoline+Park+good+in+the+month+of+January!+Burn+1%2c000+calories+and+have+fun!+Everyone+is+talking+about+it!&p[url]=http://www.urbanaircoupons.com?ref_id=1605-MB220416-2&p[images][0]=http://www.socialcampaignoffers.com/Admin/Image/Sponsors/1/FB/post_back_picture_fitness.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I also had the similar problem

use this method instead:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/